# How to have a Menu always visible across multiple layouts?

Tags: java, android, menu

I have looked quite a few places but can't seem to find this specific solution. I am interested in creating a menu that will always be visible across every layout/view of the application. This menu would act much like the header/menu of a website that is fixed and always exists across all pages of the site. I assume I can simply create a menu and have it's visibility shown from initialization but I'm not sure if that's the best way. I don't want the user to have to click any other buttons to open the menu, I just want it fixed and constantly visible from the start of the app.

Thank you.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you learned about fragments yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragments, they are a way to define parts of the user interface. They are similar to activities, they have their own lifecycle. They are also closely tied to the life cycle of their parent activity.

You can add them statically by declaring them in your xml manifest and in your layout file

-or-

you can add them dynamically in runtime by creating them as java objects and xml layout files and then add them using the FragmentManager class.

check out the Documentation on the android developer website

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

also, check out some tutorials on youtube, I like these ones especially:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GyGtCMoR_U&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW4lMlpHgL7UNQSGMERcDzHo
Good Luck!

Comment: Wow! Thank you that video is incredible and I had no idea about Fragments. They seem extremely important for the experience I'm trying to create. Thank you.